# Uncaught (in promise) Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am new to React JS, to learn it I am trying to create a news app with the help of newsapi.org. I am listing all the news sources on the landing page and on clicking on one of the news sources, I want to redirect to a link specific to that source and display all the news from that source.

I am using react-router for routing. I am trying to create a link for each News Source, but when I am using the Link component, I am getting following error

**Uncaught (in promise) Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in. Check the render method of `NewsItem`.**

**warning.js:36 Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in. Check the render method of `NewsItem`.**

File App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import './Routes.js';
import { Link } from 'react-router';
import NewsList  from './NewsList';
import Header from './Header';

class App extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.state = { sources: [] };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('https://newsapi.org/v1/sources?language=en&apiKey=c0f3800ecd5e42f5b1f5bc0e2902bddb')
            .then(result=> result.json())
            .then(json =>  {
                this.setState({sources: json.sources});
                //console.log(this.state.sources); return false;
            });
    }

    render() {

        const sources = this.state.sources;
        // console.log(sources)
        return (

            <div>
                <Header />

                    <NewsList sources={sources} />

            </div>
        )

    }

}

export default App;
```

Header.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class Header extends Component {

    render () {

        return (

            <nav className="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" className="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                            <span className="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span className="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span className="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span className="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        <a className="navbar-brand" href="javascript:void(0)">NEWS SUMO</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>


        )

    }


}
```

NewsList.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import NewsItem from './NewsItem';

export default class NewsList extends Component {

    render() {
        //console.log(this.props.sources)
        const {sources} = this.props;
        // console.log(this.sources);
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row source-list">
                    { sources.map((source, key) => (

                        <NewsItem key={key} source={source}  />

                    ))}
                </div>
            </div>
        )

    }
}
```

NewsItem.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';

export default class NewsItem extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="col-md-3">
                <Link to={`/news/source/${this.props.source.id}`}>
                    { this.props.source.name }
                </Link>;
            </div>
        );

    }

}
```

Routes.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import NewsItem from './NewsItem';

export default class NewsList extends Component {

    render() {
        //console.log(this.props.sources)
        const {sources} = this.props;
        // console.log(this.sources);
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row source-list">
                    { sources.map((source, key) => (

                        <NewsItem key={key} source={source}  />

                    ))}
                </div>
            </div>
        )

    }
}
```

**Update:**

Using react-router-dom instead of react-router fixed the issue.

Comment: what is your react-router version?

Comment: @QoP I am using react-router version 4.0

Comment: You'll have to install `react-router-dom` and import `Link`, `Route` and the other components from that package

Comment: @QoP tried it now getting following error 


warning.js:36 Warning: Failed context type: The context `router` is marked as required in `Link`, but its value is `undefined`.
    in Link (at NewsItem.js:13)
    in div (at NewsItem.js:12)
    in NewsItem (at NewsList.js:15)
    in div (at NewsList.js:12)
    in div (at NewsList.js:11)
    in NewsList (at App.js:32)
    in div (at App.js:29)
    in App (at index.js:6)